# Jetpack Compose IntrinsicSize.Min qualifier is forcing text to be 2 lines

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**This is the text i want to create.**

[image]

I want to draw a line below text by using `Divider()` but something is wrong. Let me explain.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Example() {
Column(
     modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    Text(text = "Jetpack Compose")
    Divider(
        color = Color.Red
    )
   }
}
```

[image]

**The Problem**: As you can see `IntrinsicSize.Min` force my text to be 2 lines. This happens because of the white space inside the text and I don't want it I want a single line text with  divider below it.

**What i've tried**

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Original() {
Text(text = "Jetpack Compose", modifier = Modifier
    .padding(bottom = 1.dp)
    .drawBehind {
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            topLeft = Offset(0f, size.height),
            size = Size(width = size.width, height = 1.dp.toPx())
        )
    })
}
```

Using the `drawBehind` modifier is working as i expected but i think there should be a better approach for this situation. Can we achieve this without using the modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the required width of the text composable to IntrinsicSize.Max

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun UnderlinedText(text: String = "Jetpack Compose") {
    Column(Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
        Text(
           modifier = Modifier.requiredWidth(IntrinsicSize.Max),
            text = text,
        )
        Divider(color = Color.Red)
    }
}
```

This will force your Text Composable to try and take up as much space as possible, while still allowing the Divider to be limited by the width of the Column.